# Default string value for empty field in struct

Tags: c++, string, struct

Say I have a structure called Names

```
struct Names {
   std::string first_name;
   std::string middle_name;
   std::string last_name;
}
```

Later I add first and last name to the structure, but nothing for the middle name. If I want to check at some point if middle name exists (from many structs like this) and do something to it, what do I compare it to? Is it `false` or empty string such as `middle_name = "";?

Comment: `middle_name.empty();`, `middle_name.size() == 0;` and `middle_name == "";` should all work. I prefer `empty`.

Comment: Thank you! I used empty() and it certainly works.

Answer (score 2):

The default constructor builds an empty string with a length of 0 characters. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/